# Create a file of given size in Linux and fill it with user data pattern

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, vi, dd

I need to generate a file of a certain size such as 4KB, 128KB etc .

What is a command to create a file of a certain size on Linux? I vaguely remember DD tool serves this purpose such as

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=upload_test bs=file_size count=1.
```

I need to fill the created file with user patterns

```
1.) All zeroes

2.) Incremental 1 byte Data Pattern 0x00 0x01 0x02...0xFF 0x00 0x01...0x0FF ..

3.) All 1's /any fixed value
```

Is there any command line/scripts that can serve the above two purposes i.e create a file of certain size and fill it with patterns.

Comment: You could use `dd` to copy `/dev/zero` to fill a file with all zeros.  For the other two, `perl` is probably the best/easiest choice.

Comment: For example you could use this `for ((i=1;i<=SIZE;i++)) ; do printf '\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF'; done > test.bin`
For SIZE=1024 you will get 4KB file in total. But it will be slow..
`# ls -lh test.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.0K Sep 30 12:33 test.bin
# cat test.bin | hexdump
0000000 adde efbe adde efbe adde efbe adde efbe
*
0001000`

Answer (score 0):

`perl` is almost certainly the right tool for this.  My `perl` is (sadly) a bit rusty, and there are certainly better ways to do this, but a simple approach (for your option 2) would be something like:

```
$ count=2048; perl -e 'print pack("c", $x++ % 256) foreach (0..'$count')'
```

Comment: Thanks ..Where do I specify the file name created in the above script ?

Comment: Redirect the output.  eg `perl ... > output-file`

Comment: I get the synatx error after generating a 133120 byte file and issuing the above command.ivl@ivl-Inspiron-5721:~$ $ count=2048; perl -e 'print pack("c", $x++ % 256) foreach (0..'$count')'
$: command not found
syntax error at -e line 1, near "..)
"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: `$` is not a command you should issue, it is your prompt. If you do not successfully set `count` (which you did not, because you made the assignment in an argument to the invalid command `$`) that is the syntax error you will get from perl.